# How can I implement the reactor mechanism the same as Java NIO/AIO using Golang

Tags: sockets, go, reactor

I have read many blogs on Golang networking, but most of them use `select` and *channel* to handle the newly accepted connection, then read or write data directly. But how can I implement Java-like NIO in Go?

Comment: The short answer is: _don't do that!_ Some of the capabilities in programming languages are based on their design philosophy. The Golang's asynchrony and concurrency is built upon the, so called, channels. Doing so in Java-style will be unacceptable by the majority of Gophers.

Comment: @Alirus thanks, do agree with you. The key point of the question is that I want to confirm that if there is any solution in Go, to implement the reactor io. I don't want to discuss the philosophy. Just learning a new language..

Comment: try https://github.com/Allenxuxu/gev

Answer (score 3):

Golang uses channels, buffered channels, goroutines, and `select` statements to achieve IO in a similar way to Java's NIO. Perhaps take a look at each of the mentioned .